# how to set the request method as post and add variables to post array in zend request object

Tags: php, post, zend-framework

I have an intermediate form processor that needs to take the `POST` data from the form and manipulate it then put it back into the post superglobal using `Zend_Controller_Request_Http`. Also, I need to set the new request method as type `POST` using `Zend_Controller_Request_Http`

Using `$request->setParam()` does that add it to the post data or just a hash of parameters?

So, in summary:

```
- Set the Zend_Controller_Request_Http request object method as type POST
- Set the modified POST data to the new POST request data (I imagine its setting it into the superglobals but i want to use Zend Request Object instead).
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using `$request->setParam('key', 'value');` and retrieving them by using `$request->getParams();`? Does it work? According to the [documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.request.html): "*In order to do some of its work, getParam() actually retrieves from several sources. In order of priority, these include: user parameters set via setParam(), GET parameters, and finally POST parameters.*".

Comment: Error? Nothing? Something else?

Comment: its just not adding the data to the new post request.  im trying to avoid merging the superglobal

Comment: is there a standard php way of setting the request method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, not sure what you are trying but let me just give you a few pointers.

The Zend Request object is just exactly that, an object with everything about the *Request*. To be a bit more precise the **original request** and in that regard the elements in the request should not be altered. In many ways it just takes values from common sources and makes them available through this common interface. For instance, method `getParams()` returns values it finds in the `$_GET` or `$_POST`, i.e. you'll never have to worry if your data has been submitted via a `GET` or `POST` method.

This being said, you cannot change the superglobals through the Zend Request object because you should never do that. However, you can change them directly and then the Request object will reflect any changes since they are not permanently stored.

Here's an example of what you could (but should not) do in a controller action:

```
$params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
$isPost = $this->getRequest()->isPost();
var_dump(compact('isPost','params'));

$_GET['something'] = 'new';
$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] = 'POST';

$params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
$isPost = $this->getRequest()->isPost();
var_dump(compact('isPost','params'));

// here is result 1
array (size=2)
  'isPost' => boolean false
  'params' => 
    array (size=3)
      'controller' => string 'index' (length=5)
      'action' => string 'index' (length=5)
      'module' => string 'default' (length=7)

// here is result 2
array (size=2)
  'isPost' => boolean true
  'params' => 
    array (size=4)
      'controller' => string 'index' (length=5)
      'action' => string 'index' (length=5)
      'module' => string 'default' (length=7)
      'something' => string 'new' (length=3)
```

Comment: I was trying to set the request method to POST and it was solved using this line: `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] = 'POST';` thank you